# Não consigo substituir os fragmentos exibidos no ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou refazendo a navegação de um aplicativo para que funcione da seguinte maneira: o aplicativo seja composto por uma única atividade que exibe inicialmente um `ViewPager` com três views (fragments), e em uma das views há um botão que substitui esses fragments por dois novos fragments.

Descobri [nesta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852046/3704615) que não posso usar `FragmentPagerAdapter` pois este nunca destrói um fragmento após exibi-lo pela primeira vez; como desejo trocar os fragmentos, tenho que usar `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` tomando o cuidado de retornar sempre uma nova instância de fragmento no método `getItem(int position)`. Porém para que o `ViewPager` efetivamente atualize as views em exibição após a mudança do *adapter* associado a ele (na verdade não chego a mudar o *adapter*, apenas mudo os dados associados a ele, que uso para instanciar os fragmentos), eu devo sobrescrever o método `getItemPosition(Object object)` para que retorne `POSITION_NONE` e chamar `notifyDataSetChanged()` no *adapter*. Entretanto, isso não está fazendo as views serem atualizadas (e esse é justamente o meu problema).

Segue meu código:

**ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager.java:**

```
public static class ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager {

    private String nomeDaAba;
    private Class<? extends FragmentoBase> classeDoFragmento;
    private Bundle argumentosDoFragmento;

    public ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager(String nomeDaAba, Class<? extends FragmentoBase> classeDoFragmento, Bundle argumentosDoFragmento) {
        this.nomeDaAba = nomeDaAba;
        this.classeDoFragmento = classeDoFragmento;
        this.argumentosDoFragmento = argumentosDoFragmento;
    }

    public String getNomeDaAba() {
        return nomeDaAba;
    }

    public void setNomeDaAba(String nomeDaAba) {
        this.nomeDaAba = nomeDaAba;
    }

    public Class<? extends FragmentoBase> getClasseDoFragmento() {
        return classeDoFragmento;
    }

    public void setClasseDoFragmento(
            Class<? extends FragmentoBase> classeDoFragmento) {
        this.classeDoFragmento = classeDoFragmento;
    }

    public Bundle getArgumentosDoFragmento() {
        return argumentosDoFragmento;
    }

    public void setArgumentosDoFragmento(Bundle argumentosDoFragmento) {
        this.argumentosDoFragmento = argumentosDoFragmento;
    }
}
```

**Constantes.java:**

```
public class Constantes {

    public static final ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager [] CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1;
    public static final ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager [] CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2;

    // Bloco de inicialização de valores estáticos 
    static {
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1 = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager[3];
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1[0] = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager("Aba 1", FragmentoA.class, null);
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1[1] = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager("Aba 2", FragmentoB.class, null);
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1[2] = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager("Aba 3", FragmentoC.class, null);

        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2 = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager[2];
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2[0] = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager("Aba 1", FragmentoD.class, null);
        CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2[1] = new DadosDeItemDoViewPager("Aba 2", FragmentoE.class, null);
    }

...

}
```

**AtividadePrincipal.java:**

```
public class AtividadePrincipal extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mTabsPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mTabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Constantes.CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsPagerAdapter);
    }

    public void exibirViewPager2() {
        ((TabsPagerAdapter)mViewPager.getAdapter()).setConfiguracoesParaInicializarViewPager(Constantes.CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2);
    }

    public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private FragmentManager mFragmentManager; 
        private ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager [] mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager;

        public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager [] configuracoesDeItensDoViewPager) {
            super(fm);
            this.mFragmentManager = fm;
            this.mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager = configuracoesDeItensDoViewPager;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int indice) {

            Fragment fragmento = null;

            try {
                fragmento = mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager[indice].getClasseDoFragmento().newInstance();
                if (mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager[indice].getArgumentosDoFragmento() != null) {
                    fragmento.setArguments(mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager[indice].getArgumentosDoFragmento());
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e(Logs.gerarTagParaFiltragemNoLogCat(AtividadePrincipal.this, this), "Exceção inesperada!", e); 
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                Log.e(Logs.gerarTagParaFiltragemNoLogCat(AtividadePrincipal.this, this), "Exceção inesperada!", e); 
            }
            return fragmento;
        }    

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int posicao) {
           return mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager[posicao].getNomeDaAba();
        }

        public void setConfiguracoesParaInicializarViewPager(ConfiguracoesDeItemDoViewPager [] configuracoes) {
            // Remove um fragmento extra contido dentro do FragmentoB, que se for
            // deixado no FragmentManager causa erro de id duplicado
            FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragmento = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapa);
            if (fragmento != null && fragmento instanceof SupportMapFragment) {
                ft.remove(fragmento);
            }
            ft.commit();

            this.mConfiguracoesDeItensDoViewPager = configuracoes;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Apenas para completar a explicação, quando o usuário clica em um botão em um dos fragmentos, é chamado o método `AtividadePrincipal.exibirViewPager2()` que deveria atualizar as views/fragmentos do `ViewPager`.

**Obs.:** Perguntei também no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059852/cannot-swap-the-fragments-displayed-in-a-viewpager).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o erro. Era um erro de digitação no código original que fazia `CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_2` apontar para `CONFIGURACOES_DO_VIEWPAGER_1`, de forma que os fragments chegavam a ser recriados mas as views não aparentavam ser alteradas. Peço desculpas e agradeço à atenção de todos.